# How to unlock my bit locker encrypted drive.

Tags: bitlocker

I locked my laptop hard drive disk using Microsoft BitLocker.now I install win 10 and forget my password.i don't have BitLocker recovery key so how I will open that drive please help me.
Thanks.

strong text

Comment: It would be pretty useless encryption software if this were possible :-) Suggest you recover from your backups. You *do* have backups, don't you? Seems to me that would have been a good first step before upgrading to Win10. In any case, this isn't really a programming question so should probably be migrated to one of the sister sites.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but without either the password or recovery key the drive cannot be unlocked.

This is BitLocker doing what it was designed to do.